# unable to remove stopped job with ctrl+c

Tags: shell, command-line, background-process, jobs

When I tried to change from super user to common user and therefore typed "exit",
I got an error message, that a job was stopped and I could not log out as root. 
So I listed the jobs:

```
#jobs
[1]+ yes | apt-get install build-essential
```

I moved the job from the shells background to foreground

```
fg 1
```

now I thought, I could simply press ctrl+c to end it, 
but each time I pressed ctrl+c, nothing happened except for "^c" being displayed.
When I pressed ctrl+z I came back to the prompt, but the job was still there, so I was caught in the # .

Comment: I don't think `fg 1` is correct. Why are you using 1 there? Just `fg` should work. You can just kill the job. `kill processname`.

Comment: I did not know I could use kill command with a processname, I used it only with PID.

Comment: By processname, I meant the process id. And `apt-get` should normally be interruptible with Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^C` generates an interrupt signal (`SIGINT`). It's allowable for programs to mask this signal, and either ignore it completely or 'react' to it in a non fatal way.

For example - you might want a program to stop whatever it's doing right now, but without terminating completely.

So `^C` doesn't always work.

`^Z` to stop the job, and then `kill %1`  (where %1 is the number on the `jobs` list) will sent it a terminate signal (`SIGTERM`) instead which should do the trick.

Comment: strangely, I still could not log out after ctrl+z though the shell itself was not occupied with the job the moment i sent the SIGTERM. there was still the [1]+ job entry after SIGTERM.

Comment: Yes, that's normal - a stopped process can block a logout. You might need to `fg` the process again, so it can resume and exit.